# MegaRAID Storage Manager Error 1920 "Service MRMonitor (MegaMonitorSrv) failed to start." on Windows Server 2003 R2 x64

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, windows-server-2003-r2, lsi, megaraid

I'm trying to install the MegaRAID Storage Manager 8.10 provided by [SUPERMICRO](ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/driver/SAS/LSI/1078/MSM/8.10/Windows/), but I keep getting an error 1920 that *"Service MRMonitor (MegaMonitorSrv) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services."*

I'm installing it as the administrator and I've confirmed that I have "Log on as a service" permissions set in the *Default Domain Security Settings* and the *Default Domain Controller Security Settings*. I've also confirmed that the SNMP service is installed an configured and I have the latest drivers installed for the RAID controller. Oh, I've also installed the latest .NET 1.1 updates because I read online they might be related.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this? Not sure if this matters, but the server is behind on updates and I'm hesitant to install a bunch at once... Actually, not sure if this matters to, but I get an *Invalid drive G:* error so I have it substituted with C:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this in the future the problem was with the [OpenSSL libraries](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) that were installed on the machine. Updating to the latest ones allows the service to start and the installation to complete.

Answer (score 0):

For me, an update of the MegaRaid Storage Manager helped:
With this installation, the service could be started properly.

Non-working version: 8.17-20
working version: 11.08.03.00

Answer (score 0):

For me running the msi file instead of the exe solved the problem.